# What exactly is an extended public/private key?

Tags: addresses, light-clients, public-key, hd-wallets

How do they differ per [derivation level](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin/bips/master/bip-0032/derivation.png)? For example is the extended public key of the master node equivalent for all intents and purposes as a depth 3 node's extended public key?

Therefor can I generate an address on the masternode public extended key? Will that be a valid address?